# How to use classicthesis for a collection thesis?

Tags: thesis, classicthesis

Some institutions allow the submission of "collection of articles" theses. In contrast to a "monograph", they are a set of papers published by the author, preceded by an introductory summary that explains how the articles relate to each other.

What is the recommended way of stitching papers together when using `classicthesis`?

Various discussions on this forum suggest `combine`, `pgfpages`, `standalone` or `subfiles`. Although this indicates that a solution exists, the problem is that each approach comes with its side-effects and limitations.

I'd like to tap into the "hive mind" and find out if the best practices have already been established. The documentation of `classicthesis` has nothing to say about this and the author discourages contacting them with questions of this type.

Comment: shouldn't you ljust write the summary and then join the pdf together using a pdf concatenation tool you probably don't need a thesis class at all?

Comment: One problem would be that page numbers will not be consistent. In addition to that, each document is somewhat different (margins, typeface, etc.) because it was written for a different conference or journal. Therefore I presume that the ideal solution implies the use of `.tex` sources, rather than ready-made PDFs.

Comment: sure but you need to look at what the university requirements say. If they ask for literally a collection of published papers I would expect that's what they want to get:  unchanged preprints as supplied by the journal, bound together. But thesis requirements ar weird, it all depends what they want.